# Лишний margin справа

Tags: css, margin

Не могу понять откуда берётся margin справа.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Генерирую список и элементы списка с помощью js:

```
$('#listItem').append('<ul id = "itemUl"></ul>');  

$('#itemUl').append('<li id = "itemListItem">'+prodName+' - '+prodQuant+' шт.<a class="closebutton" id = "deleteFromCart" onclick = "deleteFromCart(this)">&times;</a><input type = "hidden" id = "deleteProdId" value = "'+prodId+'"></li>');
```

Нужно переместить крестик снизу вправо, чтобы он был рядом с текстом

Comment: нет там margin же, у вас просто ширина 90%. ставьте отризательное значение для крестика - `right: -50px`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас #itemListItem шириной 90%

1. Увеличьте до ста - width: 100%
2. или отцентруйте - margin: auto
3. либо отрицательные марджины

Answer (score 0):

Если речь про часть подсвеченную оранжевым, то это не margin, это width 90%.

Еще в вас li с одинаковым id - это не очень хорошо, переделайте на класс.

Еще у вас наверное ссылка с крестиком блочный элемент, поэтому спрыгивает вниз строку. Попробуйте сделать блочно-строчным `inline-block`